# Asp.net Core Error when publish on IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-10

I published my application and got this error:

An error occurred while starting the application.

.NET Core X64 v4.1.1.0    |   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version 1.1.1    |    Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393    |   Need help?

See the log File:

```
Application startup exception: System.FormatException: Could not parse the JSON file. Error on line number '9': '"ConnectionStrings": {
"EstudantesCV21Context": "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=******;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=EstudantesCV21Context-241ea716-db64-402d-955f-be4b264ce053;Data Source=*********"'. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Bad JSON escape sequence: \S. Path 'ConnectionStrings.EstudantesCV21Context', line 9, position 209.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringIntoBuffer(Char quote)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseString(Char quote, ReadType readType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.ReadContentFrom(JsonReader r, JsonLoadSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.ReadTokenFrom(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings options)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationFileParser.Parse(Stream input)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationProvider.Load(Stream stream)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at EstudantesCV21.Startup..ctor(IHostingEnvironment env) in C:\Users\erito\onedrive\documentos\visual studio 2017\Projects\CadastroCV21\EstudantesCV21\Startup.cs:line 26
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.StartupLoader.LoadMethods(IServiceProvider hostingServiceProvider, Type startupType, String environmentName)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IServiceProvider sp)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureStartup()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\WebSite
Now listening on: http://localhost:18998
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

connection string:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "EstudantesCV21Context": "Server=myserver\SQLEXPRESS;Database=mydatabase;userid=myid;password=mypass"
  }
}
```

Comment: did you look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663759/asp-net-5-an-error-occurred-while-starting-the-application/35712042#35712042

Comment: I dont know, but I think not, I publish on Windows Server 16, and get this error after change my connection string.

Comment: That's not the resolution but follow that answer to see what the actual error is. "An error occurred while starting the application" is pretty generic to give anyone any real insight into solving your issue.

Comment: I put  log on question, i need fix the string connection.

Comment: what database are you connecting to... SQLOLEDB is really old and not used with SQL Server or SQLite for that matter with EFC...  Can you show us your Connection String cause that would shed some light on the issue.

Comment: I use sql server 2016, I will review my connection string Thanks.

Comment: I generate my connection string using data link properties, and past in my appssetings file but not work

Comment: If you get `startup` errors you can enable extra startup options to output the actual reason. Have a look at my blog post about it. http://pkula.blogspot.co.uk/2017/11/asp-net-core-how-to-fix-error-occurred.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you still need an answer to this problem. I had this problem and I solved it by changing my connection string like this.  Add double back slashes

`{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "EstudantesCV21Context": "Server=myserver\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=mydatabase;userid=myid;password=mypass"
  }
}`