# Getting exception details from failing ASP.NET Core Configure() method in Azure

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm hosting an ASP.NET Core app in a Windows Azure Web Site. I'm wondering how to get details of an exception occuring in the Startup.Configure() method? All I see is `An error occurred while starting the application.`.

One thing that DOES work is adding an app setting of `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Development"`.
Then I get `System.Exception... at X.Startup.Configure()` as expected.

But this is not a feasible solution. Azure is my Staging environment, and I'm already using the environment concept to substitute my connection strings (as suggested in almost every ASP.NET Core documentation I have ever read).

Things I have tried without any effect:

- Adding `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` (not surrounded by any `if` statement).
- Adding `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` to Web.config, as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29539669/268091
- Adding `ASPNET_DETAILED_ERRORS="true"` to Web.config, as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32094245/268091
- Enabling `Detailed error messages` in Azure portal / `Diagnostics logs`
- Adding a `try-catch`, writing a manual response, as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29524042/268091
- Deleting everything and redeploying.

Is there really no other way to achieve this, than hijacking the environment concept altogether?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518365/how-to-get-error-details-of-an-asp-net-5-app-deployed-on-azure-websites?rq=1 ?

Comment: Maybe there is a way to implement it self using try...catch                      `try {...} catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var file = env.ContentRootPath+@"\wwwroot\startuperr.htm";
                
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine( DateTime.UtcNow+":"+ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
                 
                }
            }`

Comment: @TomSun Thanks, that could be a work-around if all else fails.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would work for you, but we've decided to report these using Application Insights.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var ai = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient();
    ai.TrackEvent("Application Starts");

    try
    {
    //Amazing code here
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
        ex = new Exception("Application start up failed.", ex);

        ai.TrackException(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```