# External authentication not working when configured in 'Authentication / Authorization' settings of Azure portal

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-core

Although locally my ASP.NET Core website worked just fine, I ran into an internal server error when publishing it to Azure ("An error occurred while starting the application."). I [found out more details on the exact error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29524042/590790) by passing `.CaptureStartupErrors(true).UseSetting("detailedErrors","true")` to `WebHostBuilder` in `Program.cs`.

```
System.ArgumentException: The 'ClientId' option must be provided.
```

This refers to the Google authentication options as part of `Configure()` in `Startup.cs`.

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication( new GoogleOptions()
{
    ClientId = Configuration[ "Authentication:Google:ClientId" ],
    ClientSecret = Configuration[ "Authentication:Google:ClientSecret" ]
} );
```

During development, these are successfully loaded using user secrets in `Startup()`:

```
if ( env.IsDevelopment() )
{
    builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
}
```

[According to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-google-authentication), `ClientId` and `ClientSecret` should be specified in the Azure portal under 'Authentication / Authorization' of the web app settings. Even though I had originally specified there, the exception persists.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The *'Authentication / Authorization'* settings are seemingly just a pleasant front-end to set environment variables. This is not very well documented. Alternatively, these can be set in the (inaptly named) *'Application Settings->App settings'*.

Although the [external authentication provider tutorial for Google](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins) suggests to use `Authentication:Google:ClientId` and `Authentication:Google:ClientSecret` as keys for the environment variables, these are not the keys which are set by the authentication menu in Azure.

**If you want to load the values which are set in the authentication menu** (as opposed to just setting your own keys in 'app settings'), **you need to figure out which environment variables it sets.**

A quick listing of all variables using `Get-ChildItem Env:` in PowerShell ('Kudu', accessible from 'advanced tools' on Azure) lists the variables which should be used instead:

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication( new GoogleOptions()
{
    ClientId = Configuration[ "WEBSITE_AUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID" ],
    ClientSecret = Configuration[ "WEBSITE_AUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET" ]
} );
```

Do not forget to update the keys stored in User Secrets as well!

P.s. Weirdly enough, when I first tried setting the variables simply using 'Application Settings', they disappeared when reloading the menu. Just a heads up, that interface seems a bit buggy.